# 'Incompatible type' error with onCreateLoader() method (Android)

Tags: android

I have implemented a loader callback with my MainActivity but running into a weird issue with the onCreateLoader() method

```
package com.example.newsapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<List<News>> {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    /** TextView that is displayed when the list is empty */
    private TextView mEmptyStateTextView;

   
    //Adapter for the list of news objects
    private NewsAdapter mAdapter;

    //Get the url for the earthquake data set from USGS
    private static final String NEWS_REQUEST_URL =
            "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=debates&api-key=test";

    //Constant value for the earthquake loader ID. We can choose any integer.
    private static final int NEWS_LOADER_ID = 1;

    //Loader callback method: onCreateLoader()
    @Override
    public Loader<List<News>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "TEST: OnCreateLoader() called");
        //create a new loader for the given url
     //  return new Loader<List<News>>(this, USGS_REQUEST_URL);

        // parse breaks apart the URI string that's passed into its parameter
        Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(NEWS_REQUEST_URL);

        // buildUpon prepares the baseUri that we just parsed so we can add query parameters to it
        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();

        // Append query parameter and its value. For example, the `format=geojson`
        //https://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=debate&tag=politics/politics&from-date=2014-01-01&api-key=test
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("q", "debate");
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("tag", "politics/politics");
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("from-date", "2014-01-01");
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("api-key", "test");

        //Return the completed uri
        return new NewsLoader(this, uriBuilder.toString());

    }

    //loader callback method: onLoadFinished()
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<News>> loader, List<News> newslist) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "TEST: OnLoadFinished() called");

        // Hide loading indicator because the data has been loaded
        View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Set empty state text to display "No news found."
        mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_news_items);

        //clear the adapter of previous earthquake data
        mAdapter.clear();

        //if there is a valid list of news objects, add them to the adapter's data set.
        //this will trigger the list view to update
        if (newslist!=null && !newslist.isEmpty()){
            mAdapter.addAll(newslist);   //to test empty state, comment this line
        }

    }

    //loader callback method: onLoadReset()
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<News>> loader) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "TEST: onLoaderReset() called");
        //reset the loader so we can clear out existing data
        mAdapter.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_activity);

        // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
        LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

        // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
        // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
        // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "TEST: calling initLoader() called");
        loaderManager.initLoader(NEWS_LOADER_ID, null, this);

        // Find a reference to the listview in the layout
        ListView newsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        //to display the textview when it's empty
        mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        newsListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);

        // Create a new adapter that takes a list of news items as the input
        mAdapter = new NewsAdapter(this, new ArrayList<News>());

        // set the adapter on the listview so that the list can be populated in the user interface
        newsListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        //code to open url when tapping on an item in the list view
        newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //find the news-item that was clicked on
                News currentNews = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                //get the string url associated with current news item (using the getUrl() helper method
                // and convert it into a Uri object to pass to the intent constructor
                Uri newsUri = Uri.parse(currentNews.getUrl());
                // create a new intent to view the news uri
                Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, newsUri);
                //launch new activity with this intent (aka open new link associated with that list item)
                startActivity(websiteIntent);
            }
        });

        // Get a reference to the ConnectivityManager to check state of network connectivity
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Get details on the currently active default data network
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // If there is a network connection, fetch data
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
            // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
            // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
            loaderManager.initLoader(NEWS_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        } else {
            //otherwise display error
            //First, hide loading indicator so the error message will be visible
            View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
            loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //update empty state with no connection error message
            mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_internet_connection);
        }



    }
}
```

The error I get while compiling is:
error: incompatible types: NewsLoader cannot be converted to Loader<List>
return new NewsLoader(this, uriBuilder.toString());

This is the NewsLoader class

```
package com.example.newsapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

import java.util.List;

public class NewsLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<News>> {

    /* Tag for log messages */
    private static final String LOG_TAG = NewsLoader.class.getName();

    /*Query URL*/
    private String mUrl;

    // Constructor: Constructs a new NewsLoader based on context of activity, and url to load from
    public NewsLoader(Context context, String url) {
        super(context);
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "TEST: onStartLoading() called");
        forceLoad();
    }

    //this is on a background thread
    @Override
    public List<News> loadInBackground() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "TEST: loadInBackground() called");
        if (mUrl == null) {
            return null;
        }
        // Perform the network request, parse the response, and extract a list of earthquakes.
        List<News> earthquakes = QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(mUrl);
        return earthquakes;
    }


}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently, `NewsLoader` is not a subclass of `Loader<List<News>>`.  Check the declaration of the `NewsLoader` class.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I just added the NewsLoader class definition above as well. Right now i have "public class NewsLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<News>>". Why doesn't this work? Also what can i change this to? If i extend it from Loader<List<News>> i get more errors..